# Need help on this C++ code

Tags: c++

I'm beginner programmer and trying to get this code work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
T min(vector<T>vec) {
    T x=vec[0];
    int index;
    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++) {
        if (vec[i]<x) { x=vec[i]; index=i; }
    }
    return index;
}
template <typename T>
void printVec (vector<T>v) {
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) 
        cout<<v[i]<<endl; 
}
template <typename T>
void selectSort(vector<T>&first) {
vector<T>second;
while(first.size()!=0) {
    second.push_back(first[min(first)]);
    first.erase(first.begin()+min(first));
  }
      first=second;
}


int main() {
    int Mas[] = { 7, 15, 14, 12, 99, 180, 197, 567, 123, -101, 32, 144, 156, 177, 4, -17, -88, 18, 99, 143, -90 };
    int dim = sizeof(Mas)/sizeof(int);
    vector<int>v (&Mas[0], &Mas[dim]);
    int m=min(v);
    selectSort(v);
    printVec(v);

    cin.get();
    return 0; }
```

for some reason,

```
    while(first.size()!=0) {
```

loop doesn't seem to work.
Can someone help? 
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: have you tried debugging it to see where is does not work?

Comment: You should put the code in here instead of pastebin, if your question is answered and the code in pastebin is later taken down this post would be completely useless for future users.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't know how to post the whole code here.

Comment: First "The variable 'index' is being used without being initialized."
Then  "Expression: Vector subscript out of range"
I'm working in Visual Studio.

Comment: Your `min` is wrong, it returns an *index* but the return type is that of a *value*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `min`, the variable `index` isn't initialised.

When the first element in the vector is the smallest one, this will cause `min` to return a random garbage value.

Initialise it to 0 (that's the index of your default minimum value).

When the compiler warns you that there is a problem with your code, you should fix that problem first, even before you run the program.